# How to make the Html dropdown list selected value to be printed as a CSV?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this html code and I want when I select name from table category with export.php to export all the data only for this category name.Can you help me please?

````
     
        <select>
            <option disabled selected></option>
            <?php
            include "config.php";  // 
            $products_cat = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name From category");  

            while ($product_categoty = mysqli_fetch_array($products_cat)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $product_categoty['name'] . "'>" . $product_categoty['name'] . "</option>"; 
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <form method="post" action="export.php">
            <input type="submit" name="expo" value="Export Category">
        </form>
    </form>```
````

Comment: Why is the `<select>` outside of the `<form>`? What have you tried already?

Comment: oh no the select is okay I just want now the php code for exporting this selected value to csv format

Comment: "_for exporting this selected value to csv format_" You want to export a single value to CSV format? "_I just want now the php code_" Go ahead and write it, we'll gladly help you resolve any problems you encounter but we're not gonna write the complete code for you. Where do you have problems? Take a look at [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) maybe

Comment: Of course, I have the PHP CSV code I just needed how to catch the value from the dropdown. Of course I was not looking for the complete code.

Comment: Add a `name` attribute to the `<select>` and submit the form. Here's how to [handle forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Select should be inside the form and please follow these steps to export data as csv.
https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-csv-file-using-php-mysql/